# Scanline error fixer unable to fix the problems

Tags: landsat, toolbox

I am using ArcGIS version 10.7 and my objective is to do LU/LCC and NDVI; however, Landsat 7 scanline error fixer toolbox does not fix the problem Landsat 7 image.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am running 10.8.2 and I was able to fix the Scanline Error tool. Do this using the IsNull and Con tools in ArcMap. Link below.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-changing-nodata-cells-to-a-value.htm

Then, in Arc Toolbox, navigate to the Landsat Toolbox.

1. Edit the Scanline Error tool in ArcMap by right clicking and
   selecting Edit.
2. Double click on the Set Null step in the model and change the
   Expression field.
3. Set the value equal to the value you changed the NoData cells. For
   example, I changed my NoData values to 100. So, my expression field
   reads Value = 100.
4. Close the Model Builder and save the edited toolbox.
5. Now, run the tool on the new file you generated from the Con tool.

It works, but honestly, the Nibble or interpolated values are inaccurate. See for yourself. Still trying to decide if I want to use it or skip 2010-2012 all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just edit the Nibble step in the Scanline tool to Nibble NoData fields and you will get the same result as the the other answer without having to use the IsNull and Con tools. Figured this out later.